# Discord bot not responding/reacting to anything (JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

So I am new to the world of discord bots and wanted to try myself on this new challenge. I got the foundation running after watching a few tutorials and reading a few posts but now my problem is that the bot doesn't react to anything after starting up...

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const intents = new Discord.Intents('GUILDS', 'GUILDS_MESSAGES');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync('./commands/')
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log('made it!');
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'ping') {
    client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

All it does is displaying: 'Ready!' in the console.
After that, it doesn't react to anything anymore. Not on discord and not in the console.

Comment: Can you point to a specific line in the code you've provided that you feel *should* cause your bot to react to a message?

Comment: Almost all the way at the bottom: client.on('message', message => {
    console.log('made it!');

Comment: I believe the guild message intent is `"GUILD_MESSAGES"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because you set up Intents the wrong way.

Try and replace:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const intents = new Discord.Intents('GUILDS', 'GUILDS_MESSAGES');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });
```

with:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
       Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
       Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ]
});
```

Also, use `messageCreate` instead of `message`